# I don't know how to traverse json from url

Tags: python

I have a small code created in python and from an api I would like to go through all the
`code = url.json()["data"][0]["name"]`

But I do not know how to do it

this is my little code:

```
import requests


swf = input("write: ")


url = requests.get(f"https://apihabbo.com/api/furnis?hotel=es&name={swf}")


code = url.json()["data"][0]["name"]


print(code)
```

Can someone help me, thank you very much in advance!

this is the url:
https://apihabbo.com/api/furnis?hotel=es&name=ducha

I have tried with this code, but no success

```
response = requests.get("https://apihabbo.com/api/furnis?hotel=es&name=Gorro%20con%20Pomp%C3%B3n")

data = response.json()



for i in data['data'][0]['code']:
    print("{}".format(i['code']))
```

Answer (score 1):

`data['data'][0]['code']` is not a list. The list is `data['data']`, you need to loop over that.

```
for d in data['data']:
    print(d['code'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate through the list of received data points.

```
response = requests.get("https://apihabbo.com/api/furnis?hotel=es&name=Gorro%20con%20Pomp%C3%B3n")

data = response.json()
for i in data['data']:
    print("{}".format(i['code']))
```